# How to send commands from client to server with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I would like to send commands from client to server example change image url or label text. I have managed to get the connection working between server & client and the button clicks to work, but i cant manipulate the DOM from the index.js file. Is there a solid way to do this? My client side uses PHP to get data from mySQL database and i'd like to pass that data as array to server and render to view. Here is my code so far:

server: index.js -

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));  
});

//This is auto initiated event when Client connects to Your Machien.  
io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Client connected...');

    client.on('test',function(msg){
        console.log("i can see this in cmd console");

    // i would like to do like this but it says "document is not defined"

    //document.getElementById("mediaContainer").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";

    });

});

http.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Listening on 3000");
});
```

client: app.js -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        socket.emit('test',$("#someinput").val());
    });
});
```

I would like it to work like this rather:
server: app.js -

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.2.65:3000');

    socket.on('test',function(msg){
        $("#mediaContainer").append(msg);
        console.log("i cant get this to work");
    });

});
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. Had to make a socket.emit inside the socket.on that catch it with another server javascript file like this:

index.js:

```
client.on('test',function(value){
    io.sockets.emit('testi1',value);
});
```

app.js:

```
socket.on('testi1',function(msg){
    $("#mediaContainer").append(msg + '<br /><br />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides to socket.io, **BackEnd** and **FrontEnd**.

In the code above, you tried to manipulate the DOM like `document.getElementById("mediaContainer").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";`
 but this is the FrontEnd part.

How **socket.io** works is you use js provided by socket in the FrontEnd to emit something to the server where the socket in the BackEnd will be listening to. Then, you emit something from BackEnd in response to the received emission. You also add a listener at the FrontEnd part to this BackEnd emission and finally manipulate the DOM according to the received emission.

**FrontEnd**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.2.65:3000');
  $("#button1").click(function(){
    socket.emit('test',$("#someinput").val());
  });
  socket.on('test',function(msg){
    $("#mediaContainer").append(msg);
  });
});
```

**BackEnd**

```js
io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Client connected...');

    client.on('test',function(msg){
        // If you want all including the sender to get emission      
        client.emit('test',  msg);      
        
        // If you want all excluding the sender to get emission
        client.broadcast.emit('test', msg);
    });

});
```

This should work. Cheers!!